# Parse a ASN1 encoded Integer

Tags: java, bouncycastle

I have data sequence like this

SEQUENCE(2 elem)

OBJECT IDENTIFIER1.3.6.1.4.1.41482.3.7

OCTET STRING(1 elem)

INTEGER7029542

I can get the OctectString which in hex is 02036b4326
02 i think is the integer tag, 03 is the length and 6b4326 is the hex value of the integer
Trying to findout if there are built in Bouncy Castle library where i could pass the hex value or the DEROCTECTString and be able to get the Integer Value back.

Comment: It is somewhat unclear how your structure looks like. If I understood correctly, the OCTET STRING contains a DER encoding of an integer. Just decode in two steps, first the outer value, then in the second step the bytes of the OCTET STRING.

Answer (score 2):

I think i figured out the answer, it looks like you have to create a new ASN1InputStream and pass the value of OCTECT String into it and then read back as an ASN1Integer

something like this

```
ASN1InputStream asn1InputStream = new SN1InputStream(attestationExtensionBytes);
DEROctetString octString=(DEROctetString) asn1InputStream.readObject();
byte[] octectBytes=octString.getOctets();
asn1InputStream =new ASN1InputStream (octectBytes);
ASN1Integer asn1Integer=(ASN1Integer)asn1InputStream.readObject();
```

Comment: In recent versions of BC you can use ASN1Integer.getInstance(octString.getOctets()) instead. It is better than the above code because it also checks that there is no "extra" data in the OCTET STRING after the INTEGER.